# Examples of functions with a natural domain $\Bbb R\setminus 2\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> I would like to find a few examples of a function $f$ with a natural domain $\Bbb R\setminus 2\Bbb N$ which can be defined in a single expression.

---

**Thoughts:**

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lceil x\rceil\iff x\in\Bbb Z$, I took
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\left|\left\lfloor\frac{x}2\right\rfloor\right|-\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil},&x\ne 0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}\space$$
Similarly, it can be defined as:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ln\left(\left|\left|\left\lfloor\frac{x}2\right\rfloor\right|-\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil\right|\right),&x\ne 0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$
Another attempt is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\tan\left(\left\lfloor\left(\frac32\right)^{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}\right\rfloor\frac{x+1}2\pi\right),&x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$

but $0\notin\Bbb N$, so I had to define $f(0)$ separately (however, $\tan\left(\operatorname{sgn}(x)\left\lfloor\left(\frac32\right)^{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}\right\rfloor\frac{x+1}2\pi\right)$ works if one takes $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$).
Furthermore, it is constant on $(-\infty,0]$, which isn't quite interesting.

How can I fix this problem if I want $f$ to be composed of $\tan(x)$? Are there any other examples of such functions defined by one expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\Gamma\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)$ is an example, where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

Comment: Thank you @Gary! I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(x-2k)^2} \quad ?$$

Comment: That excludes all non-negative integers, by this is a very nice idea, then we can sum over even naturals.

Comment: I edited :) It depends also if you includes $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ or not (I do !). Otherwise you can make the sum begin at $k=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very simple and nice!

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: It's defined in a single expression, as asked by the OP. But it's not a finite combination of elementary functions. But I doubt that finding a finite combination of elementary functions which satisfies OP's requirements is possible.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, I see I wasn't precise, but fortunately, this meets the requirement.

Comment: Note that $f(x) =\frac{1}{4}\psi _1 \left( { - \frac{x}{2}} \right)$, where $\psi_1$ is the trigamma function.

Comment: The trigamma function is not an elementary function though, because it is made from the gamma function which is not an elementary function.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I agree, but "elementary functions" is not clear either. Is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\mathbb{I}_{2\mathbb{N}}}$$
where $\mathbb{I}_{2\mathbb{N}}$ denotes the indicator function of $2\mathbb{N}$, made of elementary functions ? If so, this is an appropriate answer, but I doubt this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I am somewhat confident that that function isn't elementary. Afaik, elementary functions are well-defined, although determining whether or not a function - like the ones defined in this thread - can be expressed as a finite combination of elementary functions is typically hard as you have to prove that all possible different cases/combinations of elementary functions do not give rise to your function, which is a very exhausting task. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found a function that isn't defined piece-wisely and I figured out what to do with the problematic $x=0$ in my previous attempts where I assumed $\boxed{\operatorname{sgn}(0)=1}$ as in some literature.

Let's consider a bijection $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ defined by: $$f:=\tan\left(\frac\pi{b-a}\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)\right)$$

with a prime period $P=b-a$ and shifted by $x_0=\frac{a+b}2$ on the $x$-axis.

Since we don't want even natural numbers (I don't include $0$ in $\Bbb N$), let $a=2k, b=2(k+1),k\in\Bbb N$.

My idea was to make the desired function constant on $(-\infty,2)$ and use the above pattern on $(2,+\infty)$.

Let's take $a=2,b=4$ and proceed as follows:

$$f(x)=\tan\left(\left\lfloor2^{\operatorname{sgn(x-2)}}\right\rfloor\frac\pi4(x-3)\right)$$

this works because $\left\lfloor 2^{\operatorname{sgn}(x-2)}\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}0,&x<2,\\2,&x\ge 2\end{cases}$ if one takes $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=1$.